# Please describe to me how the following piece of code reads the output from a sensor

Tags: c, interface, io, sensors

The following piece of code reads 5, 8 bit data from the sensor.
I think I understand most of it, except for the part that says "Shove each bit into the storage bytes" is <<= and |= doing the trick and if so how?

```
#include <wiringPi.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #define MAXTIMINGS  85
    #define DHTPIN      7
    int dht11_dat[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    void read_dht11_dat()
    {
        uint8_t laststate   = HIGH;
        uint8_t counter     = 0;
        uint8_t j       = 0, i;
        float   f; /* fahrenheit */

        dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

        /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
        pinMode( DHTPIN, OUTPUT );
        digitalWrite( DHTPIN, LOW );
        delay( 18 );
        /* then pull it up for 40 microseconds */
        digitalWrite( DHTPIN, HIGH );
        delayMicroseconds( 40 );
        /* prepare to read the pin */
        pinMode( DHTPIN, INPUT );

        /* detect change and read data */
        for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ )
        {
            counter = 0;
            while ( digitalRead( DHTPIN ) == laststate )
            {
                counter++;
                delayMicroseconds( 1 );
                if ( counter == 255 )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            laststate = digitalRead( DHTPIN );

            if ( counter == 255 )
                break;

            /* ignore first 3 transitions */
            if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
            {
                /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
                dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
                if ( counter > 16 )
                    dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
                j++;
            }
        }

        /*
         * check we read 40 bits (8bit x 5 ) + verify checksum in the last byte
         * print it out if data is good
         */
        if ( (j >= 40) &&
             (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
        {
            f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
            printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d *C (%.1f *F)\n",
                dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
        }else  {
            printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
        }
    }

    int main( void )
    {
        printf( "Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT11 Temperature test program\n" );

        if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
            exit( 1 );

        while ( 1 )
        {
            read_dht11_dat();
            delay( 1000 ); /* wait 1sec to refresh */
        }

        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: I  improved my answer with more focus on the bit-pushing.

Answer (score 1):

Another key to understanding this lies in the variable `j`.

```
dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
dht11_dat[0] <<= 1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[0] << 1;
```

for values of `j` from 0 to 7, inclusive, because of the integer division.  Later, when `j` is incremented to 8 or greater it becomes

```
dht11_dat[1] <<= 1;
```

And so on.  However, the `if` condition `&& (i % 2 == 0)` means that this `if` block will only be executed when `i` is an **even** number >= 4, the reason for which is not clear to me.  Is that explainable?

Back to the `<< 1` mechanism:

So for example say `dht11_dat[0]` has the bit pattern `00000001` in it, `<< 1` shifts the bit pattern left to be `00000010`.  In this way, subsequent applications of `<< 1` have the effect of doubling the current value (1 become 2, 2 becomes 4, etc) by pushing the bits left toward the most significant bit, anf of leaving a zero in the rightmost bit.

Then to fill in that rightmost bit, the `|=1` operation has the effect of **adding one** in the least significant bit.  So if the bit pattern is `00000010` after shifting left, and the next read of `DHTPIN` is high, then the operation `|= 1`  gives

```
00000010 value = 2
00000001 1
===========  OR
00000011 now it is 3
```

And then  the process is repeated every other `i` time, pushing bits (0 when `DHTPIN` is low, 1, when high) on from the right until done.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: I included the entire code. I understand the left shift that you mentioned. It makes sense. 8 bits of an int being filled.   Still I don't understand, how come <<=1 translates into read from the input pin and pass it to register. The code works BTW, I've tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets see what exactly these two operator do,
on [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm) there are some good explanations about them.

So `C <<= 1` is the same as `C = C << 1`
and `C |= 1 is` same as `C = C | 1`
`C = C << 1` is the same as `C = C * 2` (Bitwise Left Shift Operator )
and `C = C | 1` is the Bitwise Inclusive OR Operator where it compares two numbers "using" their binary form and returns 0 if both digits are 0 and 1 otherwise. For example 1001 | 1010 has the result: 1011.

Hope this helps.